# How do I fix this problems with Tikz knots and decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

so I have a self intersecting loop and I would like the intersection to look something like - -. I have used the knot package however it does not seem to be working for my diagram as I would like although it is working for the more simple diagram:

---

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
  consider self intersections]
\strand (0,0) .. controls +(3,1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Below is my code for my knot diagram:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}


    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{knots}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}


    \begin{tikzpicture}


    \draw[ultra thick] (5,3) circle (0.9);
    \draw [fill] (5,0) circle (0.1);

    \begin{knot}[consider self intersections]
    \strand[rounded corners,->-=.163,->-=.435,->-=.795,thick](5,0)..controls +(50:7) and +(130:6)..(5,1)..controls +(50:7) and +(130:7.5)..(5,0.5)..controls +(50:9) and +(130:9.5)..(5,0);
    \end{knot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid that the first picture doesn't compile for me either. I get the same error as with the second.

Comment: Now I reread your question, I suspect you have an older version of `expl3-code.tex` and are asking a different question than the one I've just answered....